# usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/localFailed to set file flags

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, permission

I have been trying to install gofortran with the command: `tar -xvf /Users/usr/Downloads/gcc-7.3-bin.tar.gz -C /`

I immediately get the error:
`x usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/localFailed to set file flags`

I tried
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*` from other answers but it does not make any difference. I am using High Sierra.

Comment: What's the chance you have a local group that can sit with you and get you started on shell commands? It looks like you're asking pretty decent questions, but without some peer tutoring, reading chown and running things with sudo and not knowing how they work can be dangerous. Do you have a backup of everything on this computer that's safe while you are learning?

Comment: I applaud your getting in and learning! I hope you can figure this all out by asking here and getting good answers and advice - just the three questions you've asked make it possible you'll get started faster with someone to guide you in person.

Comment: I do not have a local group unfortunately, but the computer is backed up. I ended up just installing through homebrew so I didn't break anything yet. Thanks!

Comment: It is awkward seeing knowledgable peeps giving kudos for a simple question and not answering it at the same time. One might have ended here simply because one is having a hard time upgrading the PHP version on an obsolete system, not trying to learn particularities of macos perms management...